# Get image path android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, gallery

I wanto to load an image into an ImageView on android. Now, i know that if the image is too large, i have to scale it so that it doesn't take too much memory.

I want to do that doint what it says here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Now, the way i get the image is via it's URI like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"text"),1);


protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

    if (reqCode == 1 && resCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    }
}
```

And if i want to use some decode*() method, i cannot do that with the URI. So my frist choice was to use:

```
decodeFile(imageUri.getPath(),options);
```

But when i do that, the path i get from the gallery are something like: /documents/image:9023

How should i do this?
I just need to open the gallery and get and image from displaying and also be able to save it as a bitmap so i can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was stuck with similar problem few days before,

1.) First convert your Uri to string

```
String SelectedImageString= selectedImage.toString();
```

2.)once you will get String path of image you can convert it to bitmap and also resize it using bitmapFactory options.

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8; 
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SelectedImageString, options);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It worked for me I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> And if i want to use some decode*() method, i cannot do that with the URI

Sure you can. Call `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`, and pass that `InputStream` to the `decodeStream()` method on `BitmapFactory`.

[A `Uri` is not necessarily a file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html), so do not attempt to treat it as one.

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont get what you are asking me to do. I mean, i tried to do somthing like:
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ContentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri), options);
But i actually dont know what the ContenrResolver is

Comment: @user3013172: You get an instance of [a `ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) by [calling `getContentResolver()` on any `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver%28%29), such as your `Activity`. [`openInputStream()` is a Java method on `ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29).